# Extracting zip file with directories in java

Tags: java, zip

I found some [java code online](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/Extractfilefilesfromazipfile.htm) to extract files frop a .zip file. In it, the following snippet occurs:

```
File newFile = new File(entry.getName());
String directory = newFile.getParent();

if (directory == null)
{
    if (newFile.isDirectory())
    {
         break;
    }
}
```

I understand what this piece of code "does" (syntactially speaking), but I don't understand its purpose. Why do you need to break the while loop if there is no parent directory AND the newfile is itself a directory? Also, how can it be there is no parent folder? I thought every file is al created in the working directory and thus always has a "parent"?

Comment: There is no while loop in this code.

Comment: The original code is in the link "java code online".

Comment: Most likely there are no file contents to extract in a directory, the extraction already created a new file of type directory. There are no futher details so break the loop. Im asuming this happens when you zip an empty folder.